# is there any way to create an windows phone app with swf flash files?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, flash

I have developed an app for android with my flash swf file. Now, I wanna create an app for Windows Phone. is there any way create an app for Windows Phone with flash swf files ? C# or C++. in both language am asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't directly display a swf on WP8. You'd basically have to write flash player for WP. It would really be in your best interest to join the rest of the web and move away from flash/flash player. Most systems are actually dropping support for it in favor of HTML5. If you're still interested in app development for mobile systems there are plenty of tutorials on using HTML5 to create cross platform apps, as well as development kits which will have the foundation for a lot of what you might like to do. One such framework can be found [here](http://joapp.com/), but like I said there are many out there.